# How to create bipolar power supplying from Powerbank 5V 3A

Tags: power-supply

I have 2 ADS1299 analog to digital converters(https://datasheet.octopart.com/ADS1299IPAG-Texas-Instruments-datasheet-17020782.pdf). I need to give them bipolar mode supplying but I must use a powerbank of 5V 3A. I wonder how can I create a bipolar supply of +2.5v -2.5v as mention in the datasheet from the 5V of the powerbank. I am new in this field. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is bipolar operation as shown in figure 54, then there might be a problem.  Sticking with TI parts, they make a "virtual ground" chip that will take in a 5 V supply and split it into +/-2.5 V rails by creating a virtual ground at 50% of the input voltage.  But ...

The problem is that now the maximum positive rail with respect to power and system ground is +2.5 V, and you might need +3.3 V to assure a high enough output voltage to be seen as a logic 1 reliably.

Separate from that, other system components still be referenced to the power supply GND which is the -2.5 V rail to the ADC.

If either of those is an issue, then a charge pump circuit mentioned above might be needed.

Answer (score 1):

TI LM27762. charge pump + postive and negative LDO. low noise and single chip.